# How do I make a Python program into a Windows app?

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, executable, py2exe

I want to turn a python program into a windows 10 or 7 app that can run on windows PCs without python installed. I use python 3.7.

I don't think this matters but just in case, here's my code:

```
from tkinter.messagebox import showwarning
from tkinter import *
import schedule
from win10toast import ToastNotifier
toaster = ToastNotifier()


root = Tk()
root.withdraw()

def shownotification():
    toaster.show_toast("Screen Time",
                   "Take a break for 20 seconds",
                   duration=5)


schedule.every(20).minutes.do(shownotification)

while True:
    schedule.run_pending()
```

Comment: You tagged your question with `py2exe`. Have you tried using that program? Or anything else?

Comment: Do a search for python to exe - loads of howtos

Comment: I have tried py2exe but it did not go well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need pyinstaller and pip

here is a link on how to download pip: https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installing/

open up your terminal and go to the same directory where your python file is.

after that go ahead and type `pyinstaller filename.py`

you can try other commands that can make your app an icon and others in this video:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lOIJIk_maO4